# All Available Tags in web.config file of asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, configuration

hi i want the list of all available tags list & desc of xml tags

Comment: It varies.  Different versions of the framework support different standard tags.  You can have different config sections depending on what options and plugins you use.  And you can define custom config sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN has a full listing of tags for:

- [v1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- [v2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397%28VS.80%29.aspx) ([detailed configuration section info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228147%28VS.80%29.aspx))
- [v3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397.aspx) ([detailed configuration section info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228147.aspx))